# Как из DELPHI ответить клиенту из SAFARI по WSS?

Tags: delphi, websocket, ssl, safari

Есть сайт, в котором `ws = new WebSocket("wss://host");`
При запуске из всех браузеров, коннектится нормально, а в safari вылетает такая ошибка:

> Error during WebSocket handshake: location mismatch: wss://host/ !=
>   ws://host/

Читал, что неверны какие то заголовки в handshake, но разобраться не смог.

Подскажите, как должен выглядеть заголовок, что бы соединение установилось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В заголовках ответа сервера был заголовок `Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://host/` его нужно заменить на  `Sec-WebSocket-Location: wss://host/`

```
procedure TForm1.WSServerHandshake(Connection: TsgcWSConnection;
  var Headers: TStringList);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Headers.Count-1 do
  begin
    if Pos('Sec-WebSocket-Location', Headers[i]) > 0 then
    begin
      Connection.HeadersResponse.Delete(i);
      Connection.HeadersResponse.Add('Sec-WebSocket-Location: wss://host/');
    end;
  end;
end;
```